# Not able to execute all the programs simultaneously

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I am trying to design a bioinformatics pipeline using snakemake, but i am not able to execute the programs simultaneously. I have made sure that all my rules run when i try to run them individually.

```
rule fast_QC:
    input:
           "/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"
    output:
         html="/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.html",
         zip="/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.zip",
         gz="/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.fa"
    params:""
    log:
       "/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.log"
    shell:
        "fastqc {input}"

rule trim_galore:
     input:
     "/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.fa"
     output:
      html = "/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.html",
      zip = "/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.zip",
      gz = "/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_0012.gz"
     params:""
     log:
        "/home/pal/processed_BU243_S1_L001_R1_001.gz.log"
    shell:
        "trim_galore -a AACTGTAGGCACCATCAAT --length 18 --dont_gzip {input}"
```

I execute the file using command

```
snakemake --snakefile example.smake --dryrun
```

I only see only rule that has executed (i.e fast_QC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [add a target rule](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html#step-7-adding-a-target-rule) where you specify the filename of last rule in your workflow. It is customary to name this target rule as `all`. I further modified the code to use wildcards for your sample. So, now you may just add more samples to `sample_list`, and your workflow will scale appropriately.

```
sample_list = ['BU243_S1_L001_R1_001']

rule all:
    input:
        expand("/home/pal/{sample}.html",
                    sample=sample_list)


rule fast_QC:
    input:
        "/home/pal/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        html="/home/pal/{sample}.html",
        zip="/home/pal/{sample}.zip",
        gz="/home/pal/{sample}.fa"
    params:""
    log:
    "/home/pal/{sample}.log"
    shell:
        "fastqc {input}"

rule trim_galore:
    input:
        "/home/pal/{sample}.fa"
    output:
        html = "/home/pal/{sample}.html",
        zip = "/home/pal/{sample}.zip",
        gz = "/home/pal/{sample}2.gz"
    params:""
    log:
        "/home/pal/processed_{sample}.gz.log"
    shell:
        "trim_galore -a AACTGTAGGCACCATCAAT --length 18 --dont_gzip {input}"
```

While executing snakemake command:

- Don't use `--dryrun` in your commandline as it just shows the rules that will be executed but will not actually run them.
- Use `--jobs` option to specify most number of jobs that can be run at once. If not specified, only one job will be run at a time as its default value if `1`.

Comment: So, my final command should look like this?     snakemake --snakefile example.smake --jobs 10 --dryrun

Comment: Skip `--dryrun` from your command. From documentation, [dryrun](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#EXECUTION) means "Do not execute anything, and display what would be done". Note that if `-j` exceeds no. of cores available in your machine, snakemake will automatically account for it.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question. What you need is `rule all` i.e [target rule](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html#step-7-adding-a-target-rule). For example, add `"/home/pal/BU243_S1_L001_R1_0012.gz"` to your target rule. You will still need to remove `--dryrun` from your snakemake command.